# Extract data from text file using batch program

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm new to bat command, so need your help.
I want to extract `file names` (without extension) and a `user name` which is after `space`. I've tried with below code, but I'm having truble extracting user names.
I did try adding 2nd token but same result.

**Program:**

```
for /f "tokens=12 delims=\. " %%a in (D:\Autotest_Find\11-09-2018.txt) do echo %%a, >> 1.txt
```

**Input data:**

```
\\abc\sdsds\sdfsad\test10\dd.2300\src\dd\python\general\jtt\file1.seq:#11-Aug-2017  sherryw                 Initial
\\abc\sdsds\sdfsad\test10\dd.2300\src\dd\python\general\jtt\file2.seq:#01-Aug-2017  mxnf1e (Firstname Surname)      Initial
\\abc\sdsds\sdfsad\test10\dd.2300\src\dd\python\general\jtt\file3.seq:#01-Aug-2017  fgfgfg(Firstname Surname)      Initial
```

**Current output:**

```
file1,
file2,
file3,
```

**Desired output:**

```
file1,sherryw
file2,mxnf1e
file3,fgfgfg
```

Answer (score 0):

After again doing some search on net, now I'm able to do what I want. Code is below:

```
for /f "tokens=12,14 delims=\.( " %%a in (D:\Autotest_Find\11-09-2018.txt) do echo %%a,%%b >> 1.txt
```

I was not aware that one should use second variable `(here %%b)` to print `2nd token (here 14)`.

Output:

```
file1,sherryw 
file2,mxnf1e 
file3,fgfgfg
```

Comment: Perhaps this is more "coherent": `(for /f "tokens=11,12 delims=\( " %%a in (D:\Autotest_Find\11-09-2018.txt) do echo %%~Na,%%b) > 1.txt`